# Wierd Crash on iphone app

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

i have a strange reaction with my app.
My app is working fine in almost 10 different devices and also has passed the tests and it's online. But one friend that has iPhone 5s with iOS 9.1 has an issue. When he tries to enter to a table view, which i append items to it with an API call with alamofire and swiftyjson.. the app crashes. From crashlytics i get this strange error

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Events Near Me                 0x1000a532c specialized listMapViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath : NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (listMapViewController.swift:196)
1  Events Near Me                 0x1000a3c94 @objc listMapViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath : NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (listMapViewController.swift)
2  UIKit                          0x18a37220c -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 688
3  UIKit                          0x18a372364 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 80
4  UIKit                          0x18a3617b8 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2440
5  UIKit                          0x18a376f0c -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 104
6  UIKit                          0x18a10f22c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 176
7  UIKit                          0x18a01f7ac -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 644
8  QuartzCore                     0x18981eb58 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
9  QuartzCore                     0x189819764 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
10 QuartzCore                     0x189819624 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
11 QuartzCore                     0x189818cc0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
12 QuartzCore                     0x189818a08 CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
13 QuartzCore                     0x1898120f8 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
14 CoreFoundation                 0x184a47bd0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
15 CoreFoundation                 0x184a45974 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
16 CoreFoundation                 0x184a45da4 __CFRunLoopRun + 928
17 CoreFoundation                 0x184974ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
18 GraphicsServices               0x18fbb0088 GSEventRunModal + 180
19 UIKit                          0x18a08cffc UIApplicationMain + 204
20 Events Near Me                 0x100095eec main (AppDelegate.swift:15)
21 libdyld.dylib                  0x199da28b8 start + 4
```

And in the line 196 this is the code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! locationEventsTableViewCell



var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]

cell.eventTitle.text = dict["eventName"] as? String  //here is the issue
```

So to explain you a bit, with this app you get some events near you depending on your location. I have a protection if there are no events there is a message. But we leave a couple of blocks away and i can get events, among with the cell.eventTitle... but my friend's iPhone crashes through it.

Any idea?

P.S. i'm now downloading iOS 9.1 to my simulator. Another friend with iPhone 5 doesnt have that issue.

Comment: I don't have a guess on why it's crashing, but since you know the person, maybe you can hook up your friend's phone to Xcode and see if you hit an exception breakpoint?

Comment: @conarch Crashlytics reports say to you the exact location that there was an exception. This is why im curious... even iphone 5 jailbroken has no crashes at all... even ipod touch 2 !!!

Comment: I suggested connecting directly mainly because, if you can hit an exception breakpoint, you can then inspect the state of the app to see what's messing with your friend's phone.  Rather than stabbing at stack traces, you can actually SEE it.  I'd take advantage of that if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that other iphones doesn't have this problem I assumed that your friend's iphone maybe is overloaded from apps or anything else and it doesn't take the json variables in time!
So I  suggest first to use if statements to avoid errors like this:

```
if dict["eventName"] as? String != nil {
cell.eventTitle.text = dict["eventName"] as? String  
}
```

And if you want in your next update maybe you could use completions to reload your tableView data.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So in this case i have to re-ensure that the table view will be reloaded as soon as the json data is ready, i guess with promises. Because even if i change all the appends to the cells it wont appear any data. Or am i wrong?

Comment: Yes you're right the if statements solution is only to avoid the errors as I say in my answer. But if you refresh the view like go back and again to tableview or if you have a refresh button it will be reload it fine (because of cache)